# Force 2-factor authentication across bim360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Since BIM360 allows users to disable 2-factor authentication for themselves one of our clients requires a way to prevent access to files / monitor if users turn this feature off.

For forge-applications managed by me I got this covered through following endpoint :
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/users-@me-GET/

Problem is, users without 2-fa can then still access the files if they go directly through the BIM 360 docs webapp (docs.b360.autodesk.com). Is there a way to restrict acces on the bim360docs platform based solely on 2-fa or a way to use the users-@me endpoint in a way that allows me to monitor a project when those users aren't logging in on my applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this information is only accessible for the current user (who authorized the 3 legged access token).